# Django1.8 Class-based-view for authenticated file uploads

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Am new to Django and trying to write a HTTP server that accepts file uploads via POST only after authentication. Quite a few tutorials suggested CBV over function based views but when I try to do a POST, following error is thrown. Can anyone please help with what am doing wrong?

```
Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop.
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.1.100.2', 30338)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in
  _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.1.100.2', 30339)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in 
  _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.1.100.2', 30340)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in 
  _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
----------------------------------------
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import my_app.views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^post/', my_app.views.Handler.as_view(), name='my_app'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.http import Http404
from django.views.generic.base import View
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import cgi
import urlparse
import datetime
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class Handler(View, BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(self):
        print "send header"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_AUTHHEAD(self):
        print "send header"
        self.send_response(401)
        self.send_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=\"Test\"')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == None:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write('no auth header received')
            pass
        elif self.headers.getheader('Authorization') == 'Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0':
            self.do_HEAD()
            self.wfile.write(self.headers.getheader('Authorization'))
            self.wfile.write('authenticated!')
            parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
            message_parts = [
                'CLIENT VALUES:',
                'client_address=%s (%s)' % (self.client_address,
                                            self.address_string()),
                'command=%s' % self.command,
                'path=%s' % self.path,
                'real path=%s' % parsed_path.path,
                'query=%s' % parsed_path.query,
                'request_version=%s' % self.request_version,
                '',
                'SERVER VALUES:',
                'server_version=%s' % self.server_version,
                'sys_version=%s' % self.sys_version,
                'protocol_version=%s' % self.protocol_version,
                '',
                'HEADERS RECEIVED:',
                ]
            for name, value in sorted(self.headers.items()):
                message_parts.append('%s=%s' % (name, value.rstrip()))
            message_parts.append('')
            message = '\r\n'.join(message_parts)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(message)
            pass
        else:
            self.do_AUTHHEAD()
            self.wfile.write(self.headers.getheader('Authorization'))
            self.wfile.write('not authenticated')
            pass


    def do_POST(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile,
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                     'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                     })

        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Client: %s\n' % str(self.client_address))
        self.wfile.write('User-agent: %s\n' % str(self.headers['user-agent']))
        self.wfile.write('Path: %s\n' % self.path)
        self.wfile.write('Form data:\n')

        for field in form.keys():
            field_item = form[field]
            if field_item.filename:
                # The field contains an uploaded file
                file_data = field_item.file.read()
                file_len = len(file_data)
                del file_data
                self.wfile.write('\tUploaded %s as "%s" (%d bytes)\n' % \
                        (field, field_item.filename, file_len))
            else:
                self.wfile.write('\t%s=%s\n' % (field, form[field].value))
        pass
server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), Handler)
print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop.'
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Probably `^post$/` should be `^post/$`.

Comment: Also, your question has nothing to do with class based views. You main class `Handler` is using nothing that was inherited from `View`.

Comment: Is there a way to not use view and just the BaseHTTPRequestHandler? Django complained if I dont pass view to the class.